# Read XML Attribute VBA

Tags: xml, excel, dom, vba, soap

I am trying to get the attribute of a single node in VBA, but can't manage it using DOM

The XML looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
         <GetUserInfoResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">
            <GetUserInfoResult>
               <GetUserInfo>
                  <User ID="16" Name="" LoginName="login" Email="" Notes="" IsSiteAdmin="False" IsDomainGroup="False" />
            </GetUserInfo>
         </GetUserInfoResult>
      </GetUserInfoResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am basically just trying to get the value of the ID attribute. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try:

(Include a reference to Microsoft XML v3, I saved your xml to a file on my desktop)

```
Dim xmlDoc As DOMDocument30
Set xmlDoc = New DOMDocument30
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\users\jon\desktop\test.xml")

Dim id As String
id = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//GetUserInfo/User").Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
```

Comment: How would you check if the attribute exists first?
edit: Attributes.getNamedItem("ID") Is Nothing

Answer (score 0):

I tried using similar code to load and extract attributes from a web service provided XML file. It turns out that unless you set the xDoc.async property to false, xDoc.Load() returns immediately and then the rest of your code goes to waste.