# Parse XML using VBA

Tags: xml, vba

I have few hundreds of XML files created by Lotus Notes. I need to parse each of these files to fetch value of the attribute **form**. This attribute is part of the NameSpace at the top of the XML.

I am new to working with XML and any pointers will be quite helpful.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE document SYSTEM "xmlschemas/domino_7_0_2.dtd">
    <document xmlns="http://www.lotus.com/dxl" version="7.0" maintenanceversion="3.0" replicaid="8025762C004A879B" form="Memo">
      <noteinfo noteid="99212e" unid="8025762C004DD80B80256CA200440BB0" sequence="1">
        <created>
          <datetime>20030102T122314,40+00</datetime>
        </created>
        <modified>
          <datetime>20100319T031007,91+00</datetime>
        </modified>
        <revised>
          <datetime>20030102T122948,71+00</datetime>
        </revised>
        <lastaccessed>
          <datetime>20100319T031007,90+00</datetime>
        </lastaccessed>
        <addedtofile>
          <datetime>20100319T031007,90+00</datetime>
        </addedtofile>
      </noteinfo>
    </document>
```

Comment: There are likely dozens of posts on this topic here on SO, and many more which can easily be found via Google. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305/how-to-parse-xml-using-vba   Please review [ask], and try some research before posting.  If you try some code based on other questions, post back here with your code and a description of the specific problem you're having.

Comment: Tim, thanks for your suggestion. I had gone through several posts (including the one you referred above), though all are fetching the data from within the childnodes. My specific requirement is to fetch the attribute from within the <document xmlns=..........>. I think it is called as NameSpace.

Any assistance with the above will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show *something* here - at least post what you've tried. Example reading an attribute value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297068/read-xml-attribute-vba